# Will system restore point restore drivers?

Tags: windows, wireless-networking, drivers, system-restore, wifi-driver

So if I uninstall my current wifi driver and install a new one and it fails, will system restore point recover my old one?
horrible english sorry

Comment: What OS? What driver? Can you download the installer for the version currently installed?

Comment: windows 7, i just want to reinstall my wifi driver i'm not sure if i have the correct verison @music2myear

Comment: You can check driver versions in the Device Manager.

Comment: how do i make sure that i have the correct version? i checked the name of the driver in device manager then i googled the name and downloaded it, im afraid of installing the wrong version  @music2myear

Comment: mens pls help ))

Comment: Revert to restore point MUST restore the driver which was used while restore point creation.